# How can I make the movement of my cardviews smoother?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I am using a framelayout to hold each of my cardviews, and from which I am initiating each movement animation (left to right). But I have noticed that this movement doesn't appear incredibly smooth.

My code is below, what would you suggest to do, so to increase overall smoothness of card movement. Thanks

**MyFrameLayout:**

```
public class MyFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    private static int mWidth = 500;
    MyFrameLayout touchFrameLayout;

    public MyFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public MyFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public MyFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initialize(context);
    }

    private void initialize(Context context) {
        setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
        touchFrameLayout = this;

    }

    private float mDisplacementX;
    // private float mLastMoveX;
    private float mDisplacementY;
    private float mInitialTx;
    private boolean mTracking;
    private OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mWidth = (int) touchFrameLayout.getLayoutParams().width;
            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    mDisplacementX = event.getRawX();
                    mDisplacementY = event.getRawY();

                    mInitialTx = getTranslationX();

                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    // get the delta distance in X and Y direction
                    float deltaX = event.getRawX() - mDisplacementX;
                    float deltaY = event.getRawY() - mDisplacementY;
                    // updatePressedState(false);

                    // set the touch and cancel event
                    if ((Math.abs(deltaX) > ViewConfiguration.get(getContext())
                            .getScaledTouchSlop() * 2 && Math.abs(deltaY) < Math
                            .abs(deltaX) / 2)
                            || mTracking) {

                        mTracking = true;

                        if (getTranslationX() <= mWidth / 2
                                && getTranslationX() >= -(mWidth / 2)) {

                            setTranslationX(mInitialTx + deltaX);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    if (mTracking) {
                        mTracking = false;
                        float currentTranslateX = getTranslationX();

                        if (currentTranslateX > (mWidth/10)) {
                            rightSwipe();
                        } else if (currentTranslateX < -(mWidth*10)) {
                            leftSwipe();
                        }

                        // comment this line if you don't want your frame layout to
                        // take its original position after releasing the touch
                        setTranslationX(0);
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        // handle click event
                        setTranslationX(0);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

     private void deleteCard() {
            ...
    }


    private void rightSwipe() {
        Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Swipe to the right",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     DeleteCard();
    }

    private void leftSwipe() {
        Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Swipe to the left",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        DeleteCard();
    }
}
```

**Xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.example.testing.android.layout.MyFrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/taskViewContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

           ......

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </com.example.testing.android.layout.MyFrameLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to have a smoother movement of your CardViews within your `FrameLayout` you are going to use the [animation package](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/package-summary.html) to animate your views or their properties. There are many ways to achieve this but the [Property Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) is by far the simplest way to go. And it certainly fits your needs, since you mention that the movement that interests you is a `left to right` movement. You can animate the `CardView`s to move smoother to the `y axis`.

Read carefully [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#how) document in order to perform what you wish.

**Edit**: Probably [LayoutTransition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html) will be of use to you. Check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55wLsaWpQ4g) video to see what is it about. In short when you add/remove views in your ViewGroup, the transitions/dimension scales that take place can be animated.